# Need some help generating XML with Python

Tags: python, xml

I have some variables in Python that I need to store as XML. I have been using the python:LXML module for this so far. Not too experienced with it. Have tried playing around with various tutorials and docs, but I am at a dead end need some help.

Here is the python script:

```
    root = etree.Element("root")
coins=etree.Element("coins")
doc=etree.ElementTree(coins)
coins.append(etree.Element("trader"))
coins.append(etree.Element("metal"))
coins.append(etree.Element("type"))
coins.append(etree.Element("price"))
coins[0].text="Gold.co.uk"
coins[0].attrib["variable"]=("GLDAG_MAPLE")
coins[1].text="Silver"
coins[2].text="Britannia"
coins[3].text=str(GLDAG_MAPLE)

doc.write('data.xml', pretty_print=True)
```

As of now it outputs this:

```
<coins>
  <trader variable="GLDAG_MAPLE">Gold.co.uk</trader>
  <metal>Silver</metal>
  <type>Britannia</type>
  <price>
&#163;31.20
</price>
</coins>
```

However I would like it to look like this:

```
<root>
  <coin>
    <trader> Gold.co.uk </trader>
    <type> Britannia </type>
    <price> &#163;31.20 </price>
  </coin>
</root>
```

The  tags and their sub-tags would be duplicated for every type of coin. I have no idea how to construct the XML so that the output looks like the third code-block. So far I have tried to follow other scripts that I have seen on github and other sites but modify them to suit my needs but my scripts keep failing or producing incorrect resaults for some reason.

If someone could help me out then that would be great!

Comment: Append `coins` to `root`

Comment: After appending 'coins' to 'root' how do I add coins inside root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply append the Element to `root`:

```
from lxml import etree

coinItems = [
    {'trader': 'Gold.co.uk', 'metal': 'Silver', 'type': 'Britannia'},
    {'trader': 'copper.co.uk', 'metal': 'Copper', 'type': 'World'}
]

root = etree.Element("root")

for ci in coinItems:
    coin=etree.Element("coin")
    etree.SubElement(coin, "trader", {'variable': 'GLDAG_MAPLE'}).text = ci['trader']  # example how to use attributes!
    etree.SubElement(coin, "metal").text = ci['metal']
    etree.SubElement(coin, "type").text = ci['type']
    root.append(coin)

fName = '/tmp/data.xml'
with open(fName, 'wb') as f:
    # remove encoding here, in case you want escaped ASCII characters: &#163;
    f.write(etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True))
print(open(fName).read())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<root>
  <coin>
    <trader variable="GLDAG_MAPLE">Gold.co.uk</trader>
    <metal>Silver</metal>
    <type>Britannia</type>
  </coin>
  <coin>
    <trader variable="GLDAG_MAPLE">copper.co.uk</trader>
    <metal>Copper</metal>
    <type>World</type>
  </coin>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the lxml builder (https://lxml.de/api/lxml.builder.ElementMaker-class.html) because imho it is easier to see the structure of your XML document.

```
from lxml.builder import E
root = E.root(
    E.coin(
        E.trader("Gold.co.uk",
            variable="GLDAG_MAPLE"),
        E.metal("silver"),
        E.price("&#163;31.20")
        )
    )
```

You can then append the `root` element to your main document.

Comment: Neat, had no idea that this existed